# Cómo ejecutar un archivo .sh desde Excel 2011 en MAC?

Tags: excel, macos

Cómo están?

Necesito por favor me ayuden con algo:

Necesito ejecutar un archivo con extensión .sh, desde Visual Basic de Excel 2011 de MAC.
Cómo es la sintaxis?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

No dispongo de un mac pero seguramente sea con este comando:

> MacScript("do shell script ""commando""")

Te adjunto información oficial [LINK](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/macscript-function)

EDIT:

Al parecer esta obsoleto. Y se usa:

> ```
> Dim myScriptResult as String
> myScriptResult = AppleScriptTask ("MyAppleScriptFile.applescript", "myapplescripthandler", "my parameter string")
> ```

Te adjunto también un [LINK](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/office-mac/applescripttask)